# Which index should I use for $geoWithin searching?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose, mongodb-query, geospatial

I'm querying documents by their locations with the following criteria

```
db.collection.find({
    "location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$box": [
                [165.8694369, -52.61941849999999],
                [-175.831536, -29.2313419]
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Which index type should I use for location field either `2d` or `2dsphere`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [**documentation**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#behavior).

> The query calculates distances using flat (planar) geometry.
>
> Changed in version 2.2.3: Applications can use $box without having a geospatial index. However, geospatial indexes support much faster queries than the unindexed equivalents. Before 2.2.3, a geospatial index must exist on a field holding coordinates before using any of the geospatial query operators.
>
> Only the 2d geospatial index supports $box.

---

> Spherical
>
> To calculate geometry over an Earth-like sphere, store your location data on a spherical surface and use 2dsphere index.
>
> Store your location data as GeoJSON objects with this coordinate-axis order: longitude, latitude. The coordinate reference system for GeoJSON uses the WGS84 datum.

---

> Flat
>
> To calculate distances on a Euclidean plane, store your location data as legacy coordinate pairs and use a 2d index.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But $box is just an example so I could use $geometry with Poligon instead

Comment: @Erik you may need to read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#geospatial-indexes-and-queries)

Comment: Thanks for the reference but I don't understand yet which type of surface should I use flat or spherical for my query?

Comment: @Erik added more infos to my answer